# BaseExpandableListAdapter not working

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've have implemented a custom `BaseExpandableListAdapter` for my `ExpandableListView`. But when I set the adapter to the list it calls the `getGroupCount()` method, which returns 4, but the rest of the methods are never called and the row views are never created. Do you have any idea?

**PendientesAdapter:**

```
public class PendientesAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Map<String, List<Purchase>> mGroupedReviews;
    private List<String> mGroups;

    public PendientesAdapter(Context mContext, Map<String, List<Purchase>> mGroupedReviews) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mGroupedReviews = mGroupedReviews;
        this.mGroups = new ArrayList<>(mGroupedReviews.keySet());
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "KEYS: " + mGroups);
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "VALUES: " + mGroupedReviews);
    }

    public void reloadData(Map<String, List<Purchase>> mGroupedReviews) {
        this.mGroupedReviews = mGroupedReviews;
        this.mGroups = new ArrayList<>(mGroupedReviews.keySet());
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "getGroupCount: " + mGroups.size());
        return mGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        String group = getGroup(i);
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "getChildrenCount: " + mGroupedReviews.get(group).size());
        return mGroupedReviews.get(group).size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int i) {
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "getGroup: " + mGroups.get(i));
        return mGroups.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Purchase getChild(int i, int i1) {
        String group = getGroup(i);
        return mGroupedReviews.get(group).get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "getGroupView");

        GroupViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_reviews_group, null);
            holder = new GroupViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            view.setTag(view);
        } else {
            holder = (GroupViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(getGroup(i));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "getChildView");

        PurchaseViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_pendientes, null);
            holder = new PurchaseViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PurchaseViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Purchase purchase = getChild(i, i1);
        holder.name.setText(purchase.getComercio().getName());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }

    private class GroupViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
    }

    private class PurchaseViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
    }
}
```

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml layout containing the ExpandableListView?

Comment: Xml layout added @Simas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your groups been shown? If so, have you try clicking on a group?
Booomm!

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to <package>.YourActivity$PendientesAdapter$GroupViewHolder
```

I think your problem just comes from this cast so :

```
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Log.d("pendientesfragment", "getGroupView");

        GroupViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_reviews_group, null);
            holder = new GroupViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            //view.setTag(view); <-- instead of
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (GroupViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(getGroup(i));

        return view;
    }
```

[image: Image of working app]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had another external problem, which I have solved. Anyway, I have marked this answer as the correct one because it helped me to find a new error on my code. Thanks!